# Unable to create same parameter value twice in json array

Tags: java, json

In this code, I am trying to creating something like this-

```
 public String KLYA_JSON_LookUp_MultiNode(String KLYA_To,String KLYA_DLRURL,String KLYA_To2) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("dlrurl", KLYA_DLRURL);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject Array_item = new JSONObject();
        Array_item.put("to", KLYA_To);
        Array_item.put("to", KLYA_To2);
        array.add(Array_item);
        jsonObj.put("lookup", array);

        CreatedJson = jsonObj.toString();
        System.out.println(CreatedJson);
        return CreatedJson ;
    }
```

Output:

```
{"lookup": [{
"to": "890XXXXXXX"
}, {
"to": "890XXXXXXX"
}], "dlrurl": "http://www.example.com/dlr.php/......"
}
```

but I dont get as per the above comment, it ends up printing only one `to` in the array where as it should print two.

Comment: You're adding _one_ element to the array and try to set the  `to` value twice. Instead create _two_ elements each with its own `to` value and add both to the array (so there should be _two_ calls so `array.add(...)`).

Comment: Btw, do yourself a favor and look up the Java code conventions, especially the naming parts. That will help you write code that makes it easier to spot bugs. As a result your variables would then be named `arrayItem`, `createdJson` (here the definition is missing, I hope you just missed it and didn't make it an instance or class member) etc.

Comment: `JSONObject` extends `Map<String,JSONValue>` so the second `put` with key "to" will just overwrite the value of the first call.

Comment: @Thomas If I add more than one array in array.add() it gives error.

Comment: @Conffusion okay, whats the correct approach to it?

Comment: Well, the correct way would be to use 2 instances of JSONObject and add those 2 to the array. If you get an error then you're probably doing it wrong and you should post the error here (include the stacktrace if you have one). - "If I add more than one _array_ in array.add()...": this might indicate a misconception on your part (or a problem with your naming). You need to add multiple _elements_ to one _array_, not multiple arrays.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I have fixed the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after Thomas and Petter's suggestion, I worked on it and this is how it got resolved.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject Array_item = new JSONObject();
JSONObject NextArray_item = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("dlrurl", "url");
NextArray_item.put("to","XXXX");
Array_item.put("to", "XXX");
array.add(Array_item);
array.add(NextArray_item);
jsonObj.put("lookup", array);
CreatedJson = jsonObj.toString();
System.out.println(CreatedJson);
```

Comment: I'll repeat my comment above: work on your naming sheme. If you look at how SO renders your code you should see that `JSONObject Array_item` has the same color for both strings while `JSONArray array` uses different colors. That's because `Array_item` looks like a class name which might result in confusion - not necessarily in your short code snippet (although that might happen as well) but once you have a larger code base using a consistent (and commonly used) naming scheme will help you spot errors faster.

Comment: @Thomas I really appreciate your comment and help but would be great if you can explain with an example as I am new to java. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Well, there already are simple examples in your code: if I'm just looking at `Array_item.put("to", "XXX");` I can't know whether this is a call to the `put()` method of the instance referenced by the variable `Array_item` as is the case in your case or whether it is a call to some static method named `put()` in the _class_ `Array_item` (if I'd just see that line I'd assume that would be the case). For some more information on naming Java code elements, have a look here: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming  (that's just one example but others are very similar).

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
array.add(Array_item);
Array_item = new JSONObject();
```

between the two calls to `Array_item.put`.

Comment: That alone won't help, he'd need another instance of `JSONObject` as well. Otherwise he'd add the same object to the array again and still overwrite the `to` value.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right about that. I'll update.

Comment: I updated it. The only diff from your own answer is I reused the `Array_item` variable instead of creating another one (as you did with `NextArray_item`).